# How to load PDF.JS and its Viewer.JS with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, webpack, requirejs, pdf.js

I'm trying to load PDF.JS and its Viewer.JS with RequireJS. Dependencies are resolved, project builds without problem but Javascript seems to crash without any error in console.

**Project structure**

[image: project structure]

If I access the static `/site/js/pdfjs/web/viewer.html`, the viewer is working fine :

[image: static viewer]

But if I access through `test.jsp` (bound to `/site/` by Spring controller), the result is just broken layout :

[image: dynamic viewer]

CSS and dependencies are well resolved in the `test.jsp` case (so it's not wrong Maven configuration of resources or so on) :

[image: dynamic viewer resources]

So I guess it is Javascript but the console is empty.

Here is the result in console for the broken layout :

[image]

Here is how I load PDFJS with RequireJS :

**test.jsp headers**

**NB** I skipped the part inside `<body></body>` since it is exactly the same as in `viewer.html`.

```
<%@ 
    page 
    language="java" 
    contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"
    isELIgnored="false"
%>
<%@ 
    taglib 
    prefix="c"  
    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              type="text/css"
              href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/pdfjs/web/viewer.css" />
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- same body content from viewer.html -->
        <script data-main="js/require/main" src="js/require/require.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js (entry point of RequireJS)**

```
require.config({
    waitSeconds:60,
    paths: {
        'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf': '../pdfjs/build/pdf',
        'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker': '../pdfjs/build/pdf.worker',
        'pdfjs-dist/web/viewer': '../pdfjs/web/viewer',
        'pdfjs-config': 'modules/pdf.js.config'
    },
    shim: {
        'pdfjs-config': {
            'deps': ['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf', 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker']
        },
        'pdfjs-dist/web/viewer': {
            'deps': ['modules/domReady', 'pdfjs-config']
        }
    }
});
requirejs([
    'modules/domReady',
    'modules/split', 
    'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf', 
    'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker', 
    'pdfjs-config',
    'pdfjs-dist/web/viewer'
], function(
    domReady, 
    Split
) {
    console.log('PDFJS Module: ' + PDFViewerApplication + '<br>');
    console.log('PDFJS Global: ' + window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf']);
});
```

**pdfjs.config**
This part is to attach `pdfjs-dist/build/pdf` to `window` so Viewer.JS can require it with this legacy call :

```
// viewer.js line 4480
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf']) {
  pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
} else {
  pdfjsLib = require('../build/pdf.js');
}
```

```
//pdf.js.config.js
define(['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'], function(PDF) {
    window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'] = PDF;
    pdfFile = 'test.pdf';
});
```

In the end, `PDFViewerApplication` can be accessed in console and dependencies are resolved and loaded by RequireJS.

I don't understand where the Javascript crashes.

I'm guessing there is something between PDF.JS (seems to be bundled with webpack) and RequireJS but I used dependency order and shim to solved this problem and yet it crashes without showing any error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please verify the order of the loaded files. Maybe there is a difference between static page and jsp page?

Comment: Indeed, the JSP page didn't have the link to the resource `<link rel="resource"  type="application/l10n" href="locale/locale.properties">`. It is working fine now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks @Paul! This really helped me.